# Constant of Holder-type Inequality for Polynomial Function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials

Is anybody aware of an inequality in the following form
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{L_p(\Omega)} \leq  C(p) \Vert f \Vert_{L_q(\Omega)}
$$
where $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $p$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. For sure the Holder inequality can be applied here but what I am looking for is whether or not some $p$ dependency is hidden in the constant that appears there?

I'm somehow doubtful that this can be done in general since the constant appears in Holder inequality looks quite sharp but I wanted to make sure of my guess before looking for other solution.
Thank you.